# Visual studio 2013 is crashing on startup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Visual studio 2013 crashed when i tried to create a new MFC project.

I have used the devenv /logfilepath and a log file got created. But in that i could not find any error.

I tried to open VS2013 in safe mode, but of no use.It still crashes.

From the event viewer the below error message is seen:

Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.40629.0, time stamp: 0x5590c8a4
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.18444, time stamp: 0x52717e84
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000451a
Faulting process id: 0x1588
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1b28302fa87ee
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 40c2c183-1e76-11e6-8d3b-005056c00008

Suggestions?

Comment: So let me get this right. VS13 works fine at first -> then you go "new project" -> "new MFC Project" -> "open" -> VS13 crashes and are unable to launch again?

Comment: New project > New MFC project > done with the wizard by clicking Finish and when the project is up. Thats it it crashed.

Comment: It crashed with this site's name, a stack overflow in the CLR is always fatal.  VS2013 is well-known to not crash like that, it is not well known why your install is different.  You'll have the spin the disable-addin/repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem to that and i had to uninstall and installed it again. I got many answers like "It's a common problem that appears after a while".

My problem solved after i installed VS 2015.

Comment: This are in many cases a viable solution in my experience. However it may be with an advantage to be able to correct the error without having to reinstall the whole thing. Both because its time consuming, and whatever causes the original error may reoccur if you dont change the way you work or the addons/nugets (or similar) that you install.

Comment: But it will always be a 100% efficient solution for problems like that, and need 30min to be completed. I tried many different ways, but nothing worked so i used this solution as my last

Comment: Yes that's true, i tried different ways and nothing worked. I am uninstalling the product.

Comment: Good luck with your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I try many solution but all no use, including force uninstall and reinstall, repair, reset usersetting, resinstall many version of `C++ Redistributable`, even after install vs2015 still no help,

Finally I find VS2015 can work normally, but vs2013 still crash, so I give up vs2013 and turn to use vs2015 in the end...